# Find stored grants on mysq tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

1. i'm looking for a way to find all privileges for a specific user. 
   Provided I have a User "John" who has read-only rights on some tables, is there any "select" or "show" to retrieve me the names of the tables "john" has the rights for? So far, i looked in information_schema but couldn't find any specific information on grants for tables.
2. Or if i set up a role via mysqlworkbench, where is the formation on this role stored in?
3. how can i manually assign a new user to this role?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SHOW GRANT FOR user` will display multiple rows of data for the user.

```
SELECT * from mysql.user where User = 'user'
```

will get the grants for the whole server.

```
SELECT * from mysql.db where User = 'user'
```

will get the grants by database.

`mysql.tables_priv` `mysql.columns_priv`, and `mysql.procs_priv` show the fine-grained grants if any happen to exist.